# List all files in Build Context and/or in WORKDIR when building container image

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I am trying to build a container image using Docker task on Azure Pipeline.
I created a dockerfile, but it looks like a made a mistake cause I keep getting

> WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/usr/src/app/package.json'

I thought it would be good to list all files that exist in **build context** and/or **WORKDIR** so it
would be easier for me to find a solution.

Is there any appropriate dockerfile command, something like...

> dir
>
> ls

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`RUN`. You can run any command you want in a container.

`RUN ls` will run `ls` and print the output of the command.